# Thread and Socket in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code.Please tell me the second method(ReceiveMSG) why not an error?

more clearly,after the success of the client1 connected and client2 connected too,

why this code not make wrong?Because in fact this class have two object of threadReceive

is running,why this code not an error?!

P.S. Sorry my English is very poor...this is my first post English article =口=||

---

```
public class Server{    
    String msgIN = null, msgOUT = "This is Server's respond.";

    public Server(ServerSocket server){
        System.out.println("Server created.\nWaiting for client to connect...");
        while(!server.isClosed()){
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connect Prot:" + client.getPort());
                ReceiveMSG(client);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void ReceiveMSG(final Socket socket) {
        Thread threadReceive = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                try {
                    while(socket.isConnected()){
                        DataInputStream dataIN = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        msgIN = dataIN.readUTF();
                        if(!msgIN.isEmpty())RespondMSG(socket);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        threadReceive.start();
    }
    private void RespondMSG(final Socket socket){
        try {
                DataOutputStream dataOUT = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataOUT.writeUTF(msgOUT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5678);
        new Server(server);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are confusing variables and actual threads. Your code works, because every time a new connection is accepted, a completely new thread will be created and started to serve it. `threadReceive` is just a local variable name, not the name of the thread. You use it to create a new [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) encapsulating your [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and then start it. After the variable `threadReceive` goes out of scope, the Thread is still left running in the background, it won't be affected by it.

Consider the following example:

```
public class ThreadTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {                   
                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println("Hello from thread " + 
                            Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }                   
                });
            thread.setName("MyThread-" + i);
            thread.start();
        }       
    }
}
```

Using the same local variable named `thread`, 10 separate threads are created and started. The threads run in parallel, and not always even in the order of creation and starting, but are not affected by the local variable going out of scope. Assigning a `new Thread` to the variable has no effect on the Thread the variable referenced earlier.

```
Hello from thread MyThread-1
Hello from thread MyThread-3
Hello from thread MyThread-8
Hello from thread MyThread-9
Hello from thread MyThread-0
Hello from thread MyThread-4
Hello from thread MyThread-2
Hello from thread MyThread-7
Hello from thread MyThread-6
Hello from thread MyThread-5
```

Answer (score 0):

server.accept() creates new instances of socket for each connection (read the Javadoc for ServerSocket). So the two threads will run in parallel each of them processing the input from a different socket.

Comment: Hi for Mr.Bogdan,thank you for viewing my question.But the two object of thread's name is the same!why not make wrong...and thank you your answer very much!!